# What is the easiest way to move images, clipboard, links from iOS to a Windows PC and vice versa?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, software-recommendation

I've used PushBullet in the past but it's been so neglected and now barely works.

What can I use today to accomplish this task?

Comment: This question might be better suited for Software Recommendations.

Comment: Are you looking to get full handoff functionality or just some cloud sync options for each of the data classes you listed? (files / clipboard sync / browser links)

Answer (score 2):

Im using Shareit - free app for iphone + free program for win. Works very fast. Only of course have some adverts as free version.